# Comparing string in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string

If I have an array like this:

```
arr = ["hey", "some", "string", "aaa", "ccc"];
```

And I want to compare if there is same string in array but with a special rule like this:

**if arr[1] == "some"**

```
arr = ["hey", "bbb", "string", "aaa", "ccc"];    //return true
arr = ["hey", "some", "string", "aaa", "bbb"];   //return true
arr = ["hey", "some", "string", "aaa", "some"];  //return false
```

I've already know how to compare string with this code:

```
var arr = ["hey", "some", "string", "aaa", "ccc"];
var val = $('#somethingFromTableForm').val();
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].indexOf(val) > -1){
        alert("same string");
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

But how to compare string with this special rule?

Comment: Can you explain what this rule is?

Comment: Not sure what "special rule" is? Why does first example evaluate to `true`, second example to `true`, and third example `false`?

Comment: try this function : jQuery.inArray(variable_name,your_array_arr)

Comment: Is it about checking if array has duplicates?

Comment: I mean if arr[1] == "some", and yes, the arr[1] value is "some", the comparing function shouldn't check arr[1] itself but other value in array.

Comment: Is requirement for `"some"` to be unique in array, and only at index `1` of array?

Comment: @S.P. Please try to explain in layman terms in basic english. Dont go technical.

Comment: I actually want to do is if there's a table and people can write down they're name on it, and first people wrote down "Charlie", the rest of people couldn't write "Charlie", my code runs perfectly on this part. But I also create a form that people can edit they're name, so if first people goes into edit zone, he thought about which name to change, but he gave up change his name and he want to quit the edit zone, but my code return false for him, I want to avoid this situation cause "Charlie" is already in the array.

Comment: So to be clear, if a user saves name (*normal  submit or edit*), you have to check if value exists in array, then return false as pushing it will make it duplicate. Am I right?

Comment: in this case, you could check the new name with simply `indexOf`.

Comment: @Rajesh yes you're right. My code works perfect when first submit, but it return false after "Charlie" goes to edit zone, but actually he did nothing but it return false for him. :(

Comment: Just check for `names.indexOf(newName) === -1`. If this returns false, value exists in array and you should not push. If true is returned, you can safely push it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and [`Array#lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf) and a check for equality for every element with [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

```js
function check(array) {
    return array.every(function (a, i, aa) {
        return i === aa.lastIndexOf(a);
    });
}

console.log(check(["hey", "bbb", "string", "aaa", "ccc"]));   // true
console.log(check(["hey", "some", "string", "aaa", "bbb"]));  // true
console.log(check(["hey", "some", "string", "aaa", "some"])); // false
```

Comment: If the question is about checking duplicates, i guess we should mark it as dupe. [#reference link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655975/check-if-an-array-contains-duplicate-values). Haven't done myself yet as question is unclear

Comment: Just a pointer, you can just do `aa.filter(a).length === 1`. `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` both will loop over array

Comment: @Rajesh, but filter has no early exit.

Comment: My bad, I meant inside `.every( (x,i,a) => a.filter(x).length === 1 )`. But your current update solves it. :-)