# Check if two arrays have non-repeating identical elements

Tags: javascript

I want to check if two arrays have non-repeating identical elements.

```
const first = [1,2,3,4]
const second = [1,2]

const result = second.every(element => first.includes(element))
//Result: true
```

But this code doesn't work with duplicated elements. For example:

```
const first = [1,2,3,4]
const second = [3,3]

const result = second.every(element => first.includes(element))
//Result: true //MUST BE false
```

How can I solve it? Please help!

Comment: Check if an array has duplicate values: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655975/check-if-an-array-contains-duplicate-values

Comment: What is "non-repeating identical elements" ? to me 1,2,3,4 don't look identical to 1,2

Comment: Alejandro, I wrote a question with google translate, maybe in the print) I mean in array [1,2,3,4] has values [1,2], bun in [1,2,3,4] hasn't values [3,3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const result = second.every(element => first.includes(element) && second.indexOf(element) !== second.lastIndexOf(element))
```

Comment: This code works for me! Thank you!

Comment: @BaglanAbdirassil Would you mind marking as accepted :)